# Calling an external API in Blazor web app

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-8.0, meraki-api

I am trying to create a Blazor web app using .NET 8 that calls an API from Cisco Meraki Dashboard API. https://developer.cisco.com/meraki/api/introduction/#meraki-dashboard-api

The purpose of this is to ping our devices (i.e. router, cradlepoint) within our network and get live updates on if they are online or not. I would need to use this API call to do that: https://developer.cisco.com/meraki/api/create-device-live-tools-ping/.

I am able to get a token from Cisco in order to access the API, which I know should go into appsettings.json. My issue is setting up the actual call to the external API. I am not sure how to configure the program.cs file to reach the API call.

Every online example seems to be an internal API call only - which I can do successfully. I've tried following a couple of tutorials and tweaking them with no success.

Comment: Forget that it's Blazor.  Look up how to send HTTP requests to an API using C#.